# How exactly was the principle of conservation of energy discovered?

Tags: energy

How did we come to know that, for example, the quantity  Work=Force*distance is conserved?

Comment: This took centuries to sort out, because in the real world *mechanical* energy is usually *not* conserved, and it is not at all obvious that there is any relationship between mechanical work and heat, for example. Most historical scientists and mathematicians with familiar names (and a few unfamiliar ones) had something to say about this question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy for a very brief summary.

Comment: You can see : [Yehuda Elkana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Elkana) (1974), [The discovery of the conservation of energy](https://www.amazon.com/Discovery-Conservation-Energy-Elkana-Y/dp/0091152402).

Comment: Old, but freely available : [Ernst Mach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach), (German ed,1872), [History and Root of the Principles of the Conservation of Energy](https://archive.org/details/historyandrootp00machgoog).